# Allow non-root user to process.setuid to certain other user

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I run a Node.js process as a non-root user with very limited rights (`limited_user`).

However, inside this application, there is a potentially attackable part which I (among other security precautions) would like to run as an even less privileged user. I'd like to do that by putting this part of the program to a different file and execute it with `childProc.execSync("node my_dangerous_subprocess.js");`
Inside that file, `process.setuid('very_limited_user');` is used to switch to a different user.

That works, as long as I run the main process as root/sudo. However, I don't want that. The process should be run by `limited_user` - without sudo rights, if possible.

So, running on Ubuntu 16.04 LS, what can I do to allow a certain non-root user (`limited_user`) to switch to a certain other user (`very_limited_user`) via `process.setuid`?

Node.js version used is 6.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can not only use the `sudo` command to run some program as administrator but the `sudo` command can also be used to run some program as certain user.

I don't know if it is possible to configure `sudo` in a way that a certain command can be executed as certain user without asking for a password.

So what you would do is:

```
childProc.execSync("sudo -u very_limited_user node my_dangerous_subprocess.js");
```

I myself would not do this because I'm not aware of the `sudo` configuration files (and I'd fear to destroy those files in a way that `sudo` does not work any more) but I can program C well enough.

I'd write the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    i=geteuid();
    setreuid(i,i);
    i=getegid();
    setregid(i,i);
    execlp("node","node","my_dangerous_subprocess.js",NULL);
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not execute node!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

(Note that `"node"` appears twice as argument of `execlp()`.)

I'd compile the program and change the user ID, the group ID and the flags of the resulting executable file (in this example the C source file is named "my_dangerous_part.c"):

```
gcc -o my_dangerous_part.bin my_dangerous_part.c
sudo chown less_privileged_user:less_privileged_group my_dangerous_part.bin
sudo chmod 6755 my_dangerous_part.bin
```

Then I could run the program like this:

```
childProc.execSync("/directory_containing_the_file/my_dangerous_part.bin");
```